# Mixing EhCache cluster nodes on different JVM versions

Tags: java, ehcache

Attempting to move over an older web app from Java 6 to Java 7, if the application and container stay the same, can some EhCache cluster nodes be on JDK 7 (or 8) and other remain on JDK 6 without any compatibility issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have any problem with this. Serialization is stable across JVM versions.